# How do I extract an integer from a string value in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, postgresql

I need to extract an integer in this string. How would I do this using MySQL or PostgreSQL?

```
user_id='12345'
```

In this string I must get the number `12345`.

Comment: And by "extract from" you actually mean to convert the whole string, not some part of it?

Comment: Wish I could select both as the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would use the `CAST` function.

`SELECT CAST(user_id AS INT) FROM Table`

**Reference**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Answer (score 4):

Besides the standard SQL syntax [demonstrated by @Daniel Li](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11437168/939860), there is also the PostgreSQL specific shorthand:

```
user_id::int
```

[The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) will happily tell you about this really basic stuff ...